# Orientation management in UINavigationController in iOS 10

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, orientation, ios10, swift3

I have a very simple app, 3 UIViewControllers in UINavigationController:

[image]

I wish the first 2 UIViewControllers to work only in portrait orientation and the last one to work only in landscape one.

I subclassed UINavigation controller and I overrided three methods:

```
class NavCtrl: UINavigationController {

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return topViewController?.shouldAutorotate ?? super.shouldAutorotate
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }

    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return topViewController?.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ?? super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    }
}
```

In my first two view controllers I added:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

In my last view I have:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeLeft
}
```

When I run the app all 3 views support only portrait orientation, my last view doesn't work in landscape.
I put breakpoints to shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations (UINavigationController) but there are called only once when the app loads and again when I rotate device but not when the view controller is pushed to nav controller.

I tried to add this line:

```
UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

to viewDidLoad to my last view controller to force orientation reload but with no luck.

Do you have any idea I could make my app to match my requirements?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for this?